# In templates in Ember.js, how do you refer to a value in the parent context when you are inside an #each block?

Tags: ember.js

I have a situation in a template where I want to use an if block on a value in the parent context while inside an each block.

The code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.view = Ember.View.extend({
    foo: [1, 2, 3],
    bar: true
});
```

The template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
{{#view App.view}}
    {{#each foo}}
        {{#if bar}}
            {{this}}
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
{{/view}}
</script>
```

This does not work because names referenced inside an each loop are scoped to the element of iteration. How do you refer to things in the parent context?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hekevintran/sMeyC/1/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a better solution.

From the Ember.js View Layer guide (http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/):

> Handlebars helpers in Ember may also specify variables. For example, the {{#with controller.person as tom}} form specifies a tom variable that descendent scopes can access. Even if a child context has a tom property, the tom variable will supersede it.
>
> This form has one major benefit: it allows you to shorten long paths without losing access to the parent scope.
>
> It is especially important in the {{#each}} helper, which provides a {{#each person in people}} form. In this form, descendent context have access to the person variable, but remain in the same scope as where the template invoked the each.

The template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{#view App.view}}
        {{#each number in view.foo}}
            {{#if view.bar}}
                {{number}}
            {{/if}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/view}}
</script>​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hekevintran/hpcJv/1/

Comment: If you are going to use inline ``view``, ``each``, and ``if`` then you are much better off using a CollectionView. It will also be faster and less dom manipulation.

Comment: Can you explain how a CollectionView will help?

Comment: @Ryan can you explain how a CollectionView would help?

Answer (score 5):

What hekevintran's answer means is that you can rename any variable using `#with`. We have a similar problem in JavaScript with `this`. In JavaScript, sometimes you'll see code like this to work around it.

```
var self = this;
doSomething(function() {
  // Here, `this` has changed.
  if (self.bar) {
    console.log(this);
  }
});
```

In Ember flavored Handlebars, something similar is happening with `view`. Say you have App.MyOuterView and another view inside it. You can work around it like this.

```
{{#with view as myOuterView}}
  {{#each foo}}
    {{#if myOuterView.bar}}
      {{this}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```

Similar to the JavaScript, you can essentially rename `view` to something else so it doesn't get shadowed by the inner view.  `{{#each person in people}}` is just a special case of that. But renaming using `{{#with view as myView}}` is the more general solution/workaround to this problem that also works with nested calls to the `view` helper.

Comment: We just spent an hour chasing this down, thanks for the answer! We kept trying to use view within an each and it wasn't being set.

Answer (score 2):

I was also stumped on this.  This thread and this other thread ([Using a container view in ember.js - how to access parent variables from child view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15705805/using-a-container-view-in-ember-js-how-to-access-parent-variables-from-child-v)) helped me with the solution. I used Jonathan's suggestion to do {#with} and also figured out that I should access my variable by calling the controller. Mine worked like this:

```
// I use the #which command to preserve access to the outer context once inside the #each
{{#with view as myOuterView}}
  {{#each myInnerArray}}
    //here, i get my 'name' property from the *controller* of myOuterView
    {{myOuterView.controller.name}}
    // stuff i did in inner array
  {{/each}
{{/with}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to place the `if` inside `each` in the first place:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{#view App.view}}
    {{#if view.bar}}
      {{#each view.foo}}
        {{this}}
      {{/each}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/view}}
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ppanagi/NQKvy/35/

Comment: The question provided the example in order to pose the question. Obviously the question is being asked because there's a need for something in the outer context to be used in the inner context. Your response does not accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @RobinDaugherty Have you looked at the accepted answer? Guess what. It doesn't address the "parent context" either. Its just a workaround. Like my answer. Magic.