# Using a container view in ember.js - how to access parent variables from child view

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm trying to access a parents view data from a container view, child view with no success.

Here is a [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/simonweil/hPtNe/1/) for it.

**What is the correct way to do this?**

Using: ember-1.0.0-rc.1.js

Javascript code:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    rootElement: '#app',
    name: 'My app',
    ready: function(){
        console.log('ready');
    },
});

App.mod = Ember.Object.extend({
    value: null,

    computed: function(value) {
        return 'computed';
    }.property()
});

App.MyController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    init: function(){
        // create an instance of the model
        var item = App.mod.create({
            value: 'somevalue'
        });
        this.pushObject(item);
    }
});

App.SecondView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'span',
    classNames: ['second'],
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("second view with values: '{{value}}' & '{{computed}}'"),
});

App.FirstView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'span',
    classNames: ['first'],
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("first view"),
});

App.ViewsContainer = Ember.ContainerView.create({
    tagName: 'span',
    classNames: ['Container'],
    childViews: ['first_v', 'second_v'],
    first_v: App.FirstView,
    second_v: App.SecondView
});
```

and the template:

```
<div id="app">
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        Test <b>{{App.name}}</b><br><br>
        {{#each App.MyController.content}}
               this should be printed: "{{value}}" & "{{computed}}"<br><br>
            {{view App.ViewsContainer}}
        {{/each}}
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting what you are trying to do. But I did find a way to accomplish it. Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sq2Dt/

You simply must climb the hierarchy of the views and then access the context like this:

```
{{view.parentView.context.value}} and {{view.parentView.context.computed}}
```

It does seem kind of strange that the context of the Views inside the ContainerView is the ApplicationController while it's parents view's context is the MyController. Go figure.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks very much, It sure works! Is there any formal documentation about this? Would you know how I can access a controllers method?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I was stumped on this too. This thread helped me down the path, but in my case, this was the solution.

```
// I use the #which command to preserve access to the outer context once inside the #each
{{#with view as myOuterView}}
  {{#each myInnerArray}}
    //here, i get my 'name' property from the *controller* of myOuterView
    {{myOuterView.controller.name}}
    // stuff i did in inner array
  {{/each}
{{/with}
```

I'm not sure why sometimes, controller is used and other times, seemingly context to access it, but I figured I'd share how mine worked.