# Action helper won't work inside handlebar's {{#if}}

Tags: javascript, html, button, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a machine_list_item.html template which contains this piece of code:

```
{{#if view.machine.isGhost}}
<div class="remove-machine-key-association">
    <button {{action "aloha" target="view"}}></button>
</div>
{{/if}}
```

And I have this function inside machine_list_item.js view:

```
aloha: function() {
    alert('Tadah!');   
}
```

The button won't call the function and will give this error:

> Error: assertion failed: The action 'aloha' did not exist on Mist.MachineListItemView

However, if I comment out the handlebar's {{#if}} structure, the code will work just fine.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `{{#linkTo}} ... {{/linkTo}}` implicitly creates a view. Many handlebars blocks do this. So anything inside the `...` that refers to `view` is actually referring to the LinkToView.

To fix this, rename your view using `{{#with ... as ...}}` so that it doesn't get shadowed.

```
{{#with view as myView}}
  {{#linkTo 'machine' myView.machine}}
    {{#if myView.machine.isGhost}}
      <div class="remove-machine-key-association">
        <button {{action "aloha" target=myView}}></button>
      </div>
    {{/if}}
  {{/linkTo}}
{{/with}}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17757739/12887) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have somewhere else a problem, here a simple example how it works correctly: http://jsbin.com/IhojaYE/2/edit

Hope it helps.

Comment: ember applications are huge. I just need an idea of where this "somewhere else" could be :)

Comment: @GiwrgosTsopanoglou, you should post more code then I guess :)

Comment: the project consists of 40+ files, are you willing to read all this code? :P

Comment: https://github.com/mistio/mist.io/tree/keys The code I'm working on has not been commit yet but all the related files are there. The path is src/mist/io/static/js/app

Comment: @Giwrgos Tsopanoglou I noticed that in routes in `app.js`, you're not calling `this._super()` when overriding `exit`. This could cause problems in your view since that's where Ember tears down views. Alternatively, you can override the `deactivate` hook.

Comment: @JonathanTran That didn't work...
I noticed the the problem occured only inside {{#linkTo machine view.machine}} .... {{/linkTo}} in machine_list_item.html.

I managed to hack it around but I will be grateful if I knew what is the real problem.

Comment: @Giwrgos Tsopanoglou That explains a lot. See the answer I just posted.